# Displaying pop-up windows in Python (PyQt4)

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt, qt-designer

I need to know how to be able to make a dialog pop-up when a user clicks a button.

I'm relatively new to both Python and PyQt/QtDesigner. I've only been using in them for about a month, but I think I have a good grasp.

Here's what I have: A main dialog (which is the main part of the application), which I designed in QtDesigner. I converted the .ui to .py using pyuic4easy.

Here's what I want to do: design a new dialog box in the QtDesigner and somehow make it pop up when a user clicks a button on the first (main) dialog.

Here's the code for my main dialog:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from loginScreen import *


class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.popup)     
        ...

        ... Some functions ...

   def popup(self):
        #Pop-up the new dialog

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   myapp= MyForm()
   myapp.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So as you can see, I've connected the first button to a method named 'popup', which needs to be filled in with code to make my second window pop up. How do I go about doing this? Remember that I already have designed my second dialog in QtDesigner, and I don't need to create a new one.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So as you can see, I've connected the first button to a method named
>   'popup', which needs to be filled in with code to make my second
>   window pop up. How do I go about doing this?

Pretty much the same way you do it for your main window (`MyForm`).

As usual, you write a wrapper class for your QtDesigner code for the second dialog (like you did with `MyForm`). Let's call it `MyPopupDialog`. Then in your `popup` method, you create an instance and then show your instance with either `exec_()` or `show()` depending whether you want a modal or modeless dialog. (If you are not familiar with Modal/Modeless concept, you might refer to the [documentation.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs))

So the overall thing might look like this (with a couple of modifications):

```
# Necessary imports

class MyPopupDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Regular init stuff...
        # and other things you might want


class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Here, you should call the inherited class' init, which is QDialog
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        # Usual setup stuff
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Use new style signal/slots
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.popup)     

        # Other things...

   def popup(self):
        self.dialog = MyPopupDialog()

        # For Modal dialogs
        self.dialog.exec_()

        # Or for modeless dialogs
        # self.dialog.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   myapp= MyForm()
   myapp.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks Avaris!
I was able to make the pop-up display, but it has the same contents as the dialog that popped it up. How do I fix that? Also, can I design the newly popped-up window in PyQt, and have my code pop that one up instead?

This is what my code looks like, for the new dialog:
`class MyPopUp(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)`

Comment: Ah, never mind. I finally understood how everything works, and I answered my own question that I posted in the comments. Thanks for your help!